# problems with cookies using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am creating a very small shopping cart application. the user only has two items to choose from that are located in a table that has 2 rows and 4 columns. what i am trying to do is the user checks the item or both items, enters the price, and also enters the amount. once the add to cart button is click, a cookie gets stored for each item individually. when the user clicks the view cart link, another table is displayed. the information that is displayed in the table is the item name, the price, the quantity, and also the total price for that one item. underneath the table, the value of the cookie is displayed. I don't get any errors when i run my program, but I'm not sure how to get the data that was entered in the 1st table to be displayed in the second table in the view cart's link. also, i'm not sure how to display the value of the cookie. here is the code that i have so far.

```
<html>

<head>
<title> Store </title>
<h1> My store </h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setCookie() 
{
var exdate = new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() +10);
document.cookie = "price="+ document.getElementsByName("Price")[0].value + ";expires=  "+exdate.toGMTString();
 }

function retrieve() 
{
document.getElementsByName("fullName")[0].value = document.cookie;
}

function Calc()
{
if (document.getElementById("calcu")){
var pri = document.getElementById("price").value;
var qty = document.getElementById("quantity").value
Total(pri,qty)
}
}
function Total(pri, qty)
{
var pri = document.getElementById("price").value
var qty = document.getElementById("quantity").value

if (document.getElementById("circle").checked) {
document.getElementById("total").value = pri * qty
}
}
function load()
{
document.getElementById("circle")
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<table border = "1">
<td> <input type="checkbox" id = "circle"> Circle </td>
<td> <img src="circle.jpg"> </td>
<td> Price: <input type = "text" size = "4"  name = "price" />$ </td>
<td> Quantity: <input type = "text" size = "4"  id = "quantity"/> </td>
<tr> </tr>
<td> <input type = "checkbox"> Stickman </td>
<td> <img src = "stickman.gif"> </td>
<td> Price: <input type = "text" size = "4" value = "$" id = "price" /> </td>
<td> Quantity: <input type = "text" size = "4"  id = "quantity" /> </td>
</table>
<br />
<input type = "button" value = "Add to cart">
<br />
<br />
<a href ="cart.html" onclick = "retrieve()"> View Cart </a>
<br /> 

</body>
</html>
```

here is my other page.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Cart </title>
<h1> My cart </h1>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function retrieve() 
{
document.getElementsByName("price")[0].value = 

document.cookie;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table border = "1">
<td> Stickman </td>
<td> <script type = "text/javascript">document.getElementById("price")  </script> </td> 
<td> price per </td>
<td> total </td>
<tr> </tr>
<td> Circle </td>
<td> quantity order </td>
<td> price per </td>
<td> total </td>
<tr> </tr>
<td colspan = "3"> TOTAL: </td>
<td> total price </td>
</table> 
<br /> <br />
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(retrieve("price")); 

</script>
<br / > <br />
<input type = "button" value = "Checkout">
<br /> <br />
<a href = "store.html"> Continue Shopping
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i am limited as to what i can use. since my teacher hasn't taught jquery, i'm not able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery.cookie if you can.

It will save you a lot of trouble. You can also use an ajax call to a php script (if you have server access and php installed) that will display the cookie values and also do some checks for hacking server-side.

Also remember to set the same domain or same page for your cookie, or else you'll end up with multiple cookies that are being read only on the page that were declared.

Hint: to use domain or page properties on plain javascript use this code:

```
document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value)+";expires="+<date of expiration in GMTString()>+";path="+path+";domain="+domain;
```

where:
   name is the name of the value you'll retrieve on the second page,
   value is the value you'll store
   expires is the date
   path is a url path, use '/' and you are system wide, or use '/cart'
   domain is the url domain, eg 'www.zubzub.com'

Now on the second page, you get the cookie like this:

```
var cookie = document.cookie;
var cookies = cookie.split(";");
```

Using the above you get all the variables stored in the cookie. So you'll have to iterate them, split them at = pos, in a way that you will get a key value pair, and then you can process the real data that are stored in the specific cookie.

Comment: how do i set the same page for the cookie. i know the way my code is written now that if i were to retrieve the value of the code lets say on my store page, that i can get it, but i'm not sure how i would get the value of the cookie to be displayed on my cart page

Comment: I have updated the code for some hints. Seriously though it's a lot of efford. Use a javascript library, it will save you a lot of trouble. If you are still looking for answers use this site [link](http://techpatterns.com/downloads/javascript_cookies.php)

Comment: when i'm trying to retrieve the cookie on the second page, do i have to use the cookie name that i created on the first page? and this is my first time working with cookies, and I don't know how to split them or iterate them. I'm not exactly sure what that means. My teacher won't let us use javascript libraries

Comment: Yes, the name is the variable. It's not a file name. Check the site I gave you it's got a more academic explanation on the cookie mechanics.

Comment: i was looking at the site, and it seems as if only one cookie is being retrieved. is that the case in that example in the link?

Comment: No, you can have multiple SetCookie() functions and multiple getCookie() functions. Imagine the cookie as a single text file stored in your computer, that every line is a variable (actually it's not but for the simplicity...). What these functions do is find that line and manipulate the data inside that.

Comment: ok, i'm seeing where you are going with this. with the example from the site, would i have to use 2 getCookie() functions, since they are using check_name as a parameter correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. check_name is a reference to your real parameter which will be called by get_cookie("panos"); You can also have a get_cookie("john") or a get_cookie("tinio"); it just checks to see if there is the specific parameter on the cookie data and give you back the value of that data. For example if set_cookie("panos",1,...) then, get_cookie("panos") will return 1.

Comment: ok, so for the getCookie() function, the check_name parameter should be the same as the cookie name right?

Comment: actually, nevermind. that answer was in your last post, and i misread what you had typed. but, i do have another question about what is in the link which you recommended me to look at. the line of code in the for loop where it says    if ( a_temp_cookie.length > 1, i am confused when the condition is true. i'm not sure what unescape means or does, and also where is says a_temp_cookie[1].replace and then gives those string of characters. i'm not sure what that means

Comment: a_temp_cookie is an array (it derives from key=value then it gets split and is an array with key and value elements). So it checks to see if it's truly an array and not an empty value (for example key=), it is explained on the comments.

Comment: ok. but could i use something else other than what's in the replacee part? or does it specifically have to be those characters

Comment: and now that i understand that part, the part i'm really not understanding is, looking at my code, how would i retrieve the cookie(s) that are stored in my store page to my carts page?